# Manual DWT vs Python pywt

Tags: wavelet, dwt

I am trying to understand Discrete Wavelet Transform. I am trying to do it manually to understand all the steps well.

Taking as an example the wavelet function 'sym2' knowing that its low decompostion filter bank coefficients are:

```
dec_lo = [-0.12940952255092145, 0.22414386804185735, 0.836516303737469, 0.48296291314469025]
dec_hi = [-0.48296291314469025, 0.836516303737469, -0.22414386804185735, -0.12940952255092145]
```

given a `x` array then its approximation and detail coefficients are:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 128)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*10*t)

cA = np.convolve(x, dec_lo)[1::2] 
cD = np.convolve(x, dec_hi)[1::2]
```

However, I do not get the same result as using the library pywt

```
cA_, cD_ = pywt.dwt(x, 'sym2')
```

The "middle" values are equal but those at the ends are not. Why is that happening, am I doing something wrong? pywt applies some additional step?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to the extension/periodization mode, or how the signal is treated outside its natural boundaries (left and right). The standard extension of `np.convolve` might differ from the many extension schemes developed for wavelets.

Since you want to develop it manually to understand the concepts, which is a very good initiative, let me suggest you to use a signal this is not sine-shaped: they are not the best to analyze and understand wavelets, as the latter are more efficient with piecewise regular signals, like concatenation of polynomials of different degrees. Here is an illustration from [Semi-Orthogonal Wavelets That Behave like Fractional Differentiators](http://dx.doi.org/10.1117/12.614791):

[image: Semi-orthogonal discrete wavelet decomposition]

And to limit the influence of extension, it can be wise to extend your signal by zeros, left and right, which remains piece-wise polynomial, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is really happening.

1. pywt first extends the signal based on padding mode. Default mode is symmetric.
2. It then performs convolution and returns only the relevant samples for the output.

The convolution is written as part of a C extension. The C extension actually skips computing the convolution for all indices. In other words, it performs convolution and downsampling together by not computing the output for every alternate position.

You can replicate the computation as follows.

Padding:

```
x_padded = pywt.pad(x, len(dec_lo), 'symmetric')
```

Convolution

```
lo = np.convolve(x_padded, dec_lo, 'valid')
```

Downsampling

```
lo = lo[::2]
```

Removing extra output values from the end

```
lo = lo[1:-1]
```

After that you will see that

```
np.allclose(cA_, lo)
```

prints True.

Same for the high pass/details part:

```
hi = np.convolve(x_padded, dec_hi, 'valid')[::2]
hi = hi[1:-1]
np.allclose(cD_, hi)
```

Lastly, the following two are same:

```
pywt.pad(x, len(dec_lo), 'symmetric')
```

and

```
np.pad(x, len(dec_lo), 'symmetric')
```

However, `pywt.pad` has support for more extension modes and its nomenclature for extension modes is slightly different from `numpy`.

Read more about [signal extension modes in pywt](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/regression/modes.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @shailesh1729, it was just what I needed to understand.